# Spark Livy Server

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hue

When I run a notebook I get this error

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused

PLease if you could help

Comment: You need to do basic troubleshooting yourself. Check that services are up, running OK and are reachable, check your firewall, AV and your connection settings. There is little we can do with the info you provided.

Comment: After that, if the error still persists, we need more details which version on which operating system you use and how you've setup the server (what are the steps to reproduce).

Comment: You need to start the Livy server, there are a bunch of tutorials around like http://gethue.com/how-to-use-the-livy-spark-rest-job-server-for-interactive-spark/